Updating actor's scalar range of ImageData in PyVista - does not update
I am writing a GUI with PyQt5 integrating a PyVista scene to display a 3D volumetric image and its sections, specifically Magnetic Resonance Imaging data. My GUI lets the user select the colormap limits (clims in pyVista). I have written the following method, connected to two independent PyQt sliders, to update the clims.
The 3D actor in the 3D scene representing the MRI volumetric data does not update, even if I force a render(), or update() - see commented parts in the following code. The clims values are passed correctly. Any idea how to solve this problem?
    def update_clims(self, min_val: float, max_val: float):
        """Update the colormap limits of all actors in all scenes."""
        self.cmap_min = np.float32(min_val)
        self.cmap_max = np.float32(max_val)

        # Handle case of empty scene.
        if not self.actor_ids:
            return

        try:
            for id in self.actor_ids:
                # Note: render is not required after updating scalar_range.
                self.plotters[SceneType.MAIN].actors[id].mapper.scalar_range = [self.cmap_min, self.cmap_max]
                # self.plotters[SceneType.MAIN].actors[id].mapper.update()
                # self.plotters[SceneType.MAIN].update()
                # self.plotters[SceneType.MAIN].render()
                self.plotters[SceneType.SAGITTAL].actors[id].mapper.scalar_range = [self.cmap_min, self.cmap_max]
                self.plotters[SceneType.CORONAL].actors[id].mapper.scalar_range = [self.cmap_min, self.cmap_max]
                self.plotters[SceneType.AXIAL].actors[id].mapper.scalar_range = [self.cmap_min, self.cmap_max]
                self.message_updated.emit(f"Successfully rescaled actor {id} colormap in the range "
                                          f"{self.cmap_min}-{self.cmap_max}.")
        except Exception as e:
            self.message_updated.emit(f"Failed to rescale actor {id} colormap: {e}")

I have written a separate script to test a 3D scene in a PyQt5 QFrame. Also in this simple script, the pyVista 3D scene including ImageData does not update the actor's clims when the slider are changed by the user. On the other hand, if I change the initial values of the sliders, the actor in the scene is displayed with different (presumably correct) colors, confirming that the problem is related to updating the clims. Here follows the script.
import sys
import SimpleITK as sitk
import numpy as np
import pyvista as pv
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QSlider, QLabel, QHBoxLayout
)
from pyvistaqt import QtInteractor


class NiftiViewer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, nifti_file):
        super().__init__()

        # Set up the main window layout
        self.setWindowTitle("NIfTI Viewer with Clims Control")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)

        # Create central widget
        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        # Set up main layout for central widget
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        central_widget.setLayout(main_layout)

        # Add PyVista plotter to the layout
        self.plotter = QtInteractor(self)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.plotter.interactor)

        # Add sliders to control the color map limits (clims)
        self.cmap_min_slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.cmap_min_slider.setMinimum(0)
        self.cmap_min_slider.setMaximum(100)
        self.cmap_min_slider.setValue(0)
        self.cmap_min_slider.valueChanged.connect(self.update_clims)

        self.cmap_max_slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.cmap_max_slider.setMinimum(0)
        self.cmap_max_slider.setMaximum(100)
        self.cmap_max_slider.setValue(100)
        self.cmap_max_slider.valueChanged.connect(self.update_clims)

        # Labels to display current clim values
        self.cmap_min_label = QLabel(f"Min: {self.cmap_min_slider.value()}")
        self.cmap_max_label = QLabel(f"Max: {self.cmap_max_slider.value()}")

        # Load the NIfTI data and add it to the plotter
        self.load_nifti(nifti_file)

        # Layout for sliders and labels
        slider_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        slider_layout.addWidget(self.cmap_min_label)
        slider_layout.addWidget(self.cmap_min_slider)
        slider_layout.addWidget(self.cmap_max_label)
        slider_layout.addWidget(self.cmap_max_slider)

        # Add slider layout to the main layout
        main_layout.addLayout(slider_layout)

    def load_nifti(self, path_to_nifti):
        """Load a NIfTI file and add it as a volume to the PyVista plotter."""
        sitk_image = sitk.ReadImage(path_to_nifti)
        image_array = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(sitk_image).astype(np.float32)
        image_array = image_array.transpose(2, 1, 0)
        spacing = sitk_image.GetSpacing()
        shape = np.array(sitk_image.GetSize())

        grid = pv.ImageData()
        grid.dimensions = shape
        grid.spacing = spacing
        grid.point_data["values"] = image_array.flatten(order='F')

        # Add volume to plotter with initial color map range
        self.actor = self.plotter.add_volume(
            grid,
            cmap="gray",
            clim=(self.cmap_min_slider.value(), self.cmap_max_slider.value()))
        self.plotter.reset_camera()

    def update_clims(self):
        """Update the color map limits (clims) based on the slider values."""
        # Get values from sliders
        min_val = self.cmap_min_slider.value()
        max_val = self.cmap_max_slider.value()

        # Update labels to display current values
        self.cmap_min_label.setText(f"Min: {min_val}")
        self.cmap_max_label.setText(f"Max: {max_val}")

        self.actor.mapper.scalar_range = (min_val, max_val)
        self.plotter.render()  # Force the plotter to update
        print(self.cmap_min_slider.value(), self.cmap_max_slider.value())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # Set the path to your NIfTI file here
    nifti_file = "my_path_to_nifti_file"

    # Create and show the viewer
    viewer = NiftiViewer(nifti_file)
    viewer.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

